# Microsoft Productivity Power Tools not working on Visual C++ 2010

Tags: c++, visual-studio

I downloaded the Productivity Power Tools for Visual Studio 2010. 
I was annoyed by the lack of the auto-completion  function for Visual C++ 2010 so I heard that this should fix it. Unfortunately it says this as I try to install the [package](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/d0d33361-18e2-46c0-8ff2-4adea1e34fef/) :

[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ySY5i.png)

Here is the install log:

```
4/30/2016 12:02:22 PM - Microsoft VSIX Installer
4/30/2016 12:02:22 PM - -------------------------------------------
4/30/2016 12:02:22 PM - Initializing Install...
4/30/2016 12:02:22 PM - Extension Details...
4/30/2016 12:02:22 PM -     Identifier         : VSProPack.Microsoft.f4ef2e6e-e531-48d5-940d-eb955306da9a
4/30/2016 12:02:22 PM -     Name               : Productivity Power Tools
4/30/2016 12:02:22 PM -     Author             : Microsoft
4/30/2016 12:02:22 PM -     Version            : 10.0.20626.18
4/30/2016 12:02:22 PM -     Description        : A set of extensions to Visual Studio Professional (and above) which improves developer productivity.
4/30/2016 12:02:22 PM -     Locale             : en-US
4/30/2016 12:02:22 PM -     MoreInfoURL        : http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=189202
4/30/2016 12:02:22 PM -     InstalledByMSI     : False
4/30/2016 12:02:22 PM -     SupportedFrameworkVersionRange : [4.0]
4/30/2016 12:02:22 PM - 
4/30/2016 12:02:22 PM -     SignatureState     : InvalidCertificate
4/30/2016 12:02:22 PM -     SignedBy           : Microsoft Corporation
4/30/2016 12:02:22 PM -     Certificate Info   : 
4/30/2016 12:02:22 PM -         -------------------------------------------------------
4/30/2016 12:02:22 PM -         [Subject]       : CN=Microsoft Corporation, OU=AOC, OU=OPC, O=Microsoft Corporation, L=Redmond, S=Washington, C=US
4/30/2016 12:02:22 PM -         [Issuer]        : CN=Microsoft Code Signing PCA, O=Microsoft Corporation, L=Redmond, S=Washington, C=US
4/30/2016 12:02:22 PM -         [Serial Number] : 6105272900010000004F
4/30/2016 12:02:22 PM -         [Not Before]    : 2/7/2011 4:12:18 PM
4/30/2016 12:02:22 PM -         [Not After]     : 5/7/2012 5:12:18 PM
4/30/2016 12:02:22 PM -         [Thumbprint]    : 445956A6B300E18DB325510DEFA4250A07F16C9E
4/30/2016 12:02:22 PM - 
4/30/2016 12:02:22 PM -     Supported Products : 
4/30/2016 12:02:22 PM -         Microsoft.VisualStudio.Ultimate
4/30/2016 12:02:22 PM -             Version : [10.0]
4/30/2016 12:02:22 PM -         Microsoft.VisualStudio.Premium
4/30/2016 12:02:22 PM -             Version : [10.0]
4/30/2016 12:02:22 PM -         Microsoft.VisualStudio.Pro
4/30/2016 12:02:22 PM -             Version : [10.0]
4/30/2016 12:02:22 PM - 
4/30/2016 12:02:22 PM -     References         : 
4/30/2016 12:02:22 PM -         -------------------------------------------------------
4/30/2016 12:02:22 PM -         Identifier   : Microsoft.VisualStudio.MPF
4/30/2016 12:02:22 PM -         Name         : Visual Studio MPF
4/30/2016 12:02:22 PM -         Version      : [10.0,)
4/30/2016 12:02:22 PM -         MoreInfoURL  : 
4/30/2016 12:02:22 PM -         Nested       : No
4/30/2016 12:02:22 PM - 
4/30/2016 12:02:22 PM - Signature Details...
4/30/2016 12:02:22 PM -     Extension is signed with an invalid certificate
4/30/2016 12:02:22 PM -         (NotTimeValid)      : A required certificate is not within its validity period when verifying against the current system clock or the timestamp in the signed file.
4/30/2016 12:02:22 PM - 
4/30/2016 12:02:22 PM - 
4/30/2016 12:02:22 PM - Searching for applicable products...
4/30/2016 12:02:22 PM - Found installed product - Microsoft Visual C++ Express 2010
4/30/2016 12:02:22 PM - Found installed product - Microsoft Visual Studio Express 2012 for Windows Phone
4/30/2016 12:02:22 PM - Found installed product - Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2015
4/30/2016 12:02:22 PM - Found installed product - Microsoft Visual Studio 2015 Shell (Integrated)
4/30/2016 12:02:22 PM - Found installed product - Global Location
4/30/2016 12:02:22 PM - VSIXInstaller.NoApplicableSKUsException: This extension is not installable on any currently installed products.
   at VSIXInstaller.App.InitializeInstall(Boolean isRepairSupported)
   at VSIXInstaller.App.InitializeInstall()
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.InnerInvoke()
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Execute()
```

Comment: The log clearly lists the supported products, and also lists the products it found installed on your system. What part of *you don't have one of the supported products installed on your system* is unclear? You should learn to actually **read the words** in error messages and logs, as they almost always have actual meaning related to the problem. In this case, it couldn't be much more clear (unless MS had someone call you on the phone to explain).

Answer (score 1):

Visual C++ 2010 isn't supported, as you can see from the log file:

```
Supported Products :
    Microsoft.VisualStudio.Ultimate
        Version : [10.0]
    Microsoft.VisualStudio.Premium
        Version: [10.0]
    Microsoft.VisualStudio.Pro
        Version: [10.0]
```

and

```
VSIXInstaller.NoApplicableSKUsException: This extension is not installable on any currently installed products.
```

Only the Visual Studio 2010 versions are supported, not any of the Express versions.

Comment: Upgrade time. VS2010 is ancient.